# Undistorting fisheye image error

Tags: opencv, image-processing, distortion, fisheye

I calibrated a fisheye lens using a set of 20 images of a checkerboard. The points are all correctly labelled and I get intrinsics and lens distortion coefficients.

Defining the 'square size' variable to 15 for 15mm gives me 0 distortion coefficients and a focal length of ~600. Setting it to 0.015 gives me distortion coefficients and a focal length of ~1200. In both cases my centre of projection is roughly the mid-point of the image which is reasonable.

When I try to apply my undistortion to my images I get a very odd result.

[Undistorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKOzt.jpg)

I do not understand why. With 0 on the distortion coefficients I still get this image. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

```
 void undistortFisheye()
{
    std::vector <cv::Mat> inputImages;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f> > objectPoints(1);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> image_points;

//Load images
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Loading: " << "C:/Data/CheckerboardCalib/" << std::to_string(i + 1) << ".png" << std::endl;

    inputImages.push_back(cv::imread("C:/Data/CheckerboardCalib/" + std::to_string(i + 1) + ".png"));
}

int chessBoardFlags = cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE;

for (int i = 0; i < inputImages.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> pointBuf;
    cv::Mat view;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners(inputImages[i], cv::Size(21, 14), pointBuf, chessBoardFlags);

    if (found) // If done with success,
    {
        std::cout << "Corners found!" << std::endl;

        // improve the found corners' coordinate accuracy for chessboard
        cv::Mat viewGray;
        cvtColor(inputImages[i], viewGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cornerSubPix(viewGray, pointBuf, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1), cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::COUNT, 30, 0.1));

        image_points.push_back(pointBuf);

        // Draw the corners.
    //  inputImages[i].copyTo(view);
        //cv::drawChessboardCorners(view, cv::Size(21, 14), cv::Mat(pointBuf), found);
        //cv::imshow("Window", view);
        //cv::waitKey(0);
    }   
}

float squareSize = 15.0f;
calcBoardCornerPositions(cv::Size(21,14), squareSize, objectPoints[0]);
objectPoints.resize(image_points.size(), objectPoints[0]);

cv::Matx33f K;
cv::Vec4f D;

std::vector<cv::Vec3f> rvec;
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> tvec;

//int flag = cv::fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND | cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW; 
int flag = cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW | cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;
//| cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K1 | cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K2 | cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K3;// | cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K4;// | cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;// | cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K1;// | cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;

cv::fisheye::calibrate(objectPoints, image_points, cv::Size(1920, 1080), K, D, rvec, tvec, flag, cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6));

std::cout << "Points detected" << std::endl;
//double rms = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, image_points, cv::Size(1920, 1080), K, D, rvec, tvec, flag, cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6));
std::cout << "Calibrated." << std::endl;

std::cout << K << std::endl;
std::cout << D << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < inputImages.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("C:/Data/CheckerboardCalib/" + std::to_string(i + 1) + ".png");
    cv::Mat temp;

    cv::fisheye::undistortImage(src, temp, K, D, cv::Mat::eye(3,3, CV_64F));
    cv::imwrite("C:/Data/CheckerboardCalib/undistorted/" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".png", temp);
}
std::string inputLine;
std::cin >> inputLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I got my code working.
Potential solution here:

[OpenCV fisheye undistort issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983164/opencv-fisheye-undistort-issues)