# OpenCV fisheye undistort issues

Tags: c++, opencv, fisheye

EDIT: I found the cause of the problem, the `fisheye::undistortImage()` function was not working correctly, I replaced it with `estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify()`, `initUndistortRectifyMap()`, and `remap()` as in the original calibrate camera example. Not perfect yet but going in the right direction. Output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zzgd.jpg

```
        Mat output;
        Mat newK;
        Mat view, map1, map2;

        Size newSize(1200, 1200);
        Mat rview(newSize, frame.type());
        //resize(rview, rview, newSize);

        fisheye::estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(K, D, frame.size(), Matx33d::eye(), newK, 1);

        fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, Matx33d::eye(), newK, frame.size(), CV_16SC2, map1, map2);

        //fisheye::undistortImage(frame, output, K, D, identity);

        remap(frame, rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);

        imshow("Image View", rview);
        imshow(window_name, frame);

        if (waitKey(50) == 27) {
            break;
        }
```

Original post:
I'm trying to calibrate and undistort an image coming from an 180 degree fisheye USB camera. Most of this code is from existing examples that claim to be functional.

The code runs fine until fisheye::undistortImage where the output image is very distorted and centered around the top left corner of the window.

Screen shot of the "undistorted" chess board and calibration matrix outputs - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhUIw.jpg

What am I missing here?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    VideoCapture camera;
    camera.open(1);
    if (!camera.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Failed to open camera." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double fWidth = camera.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double fHeight = camera.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    cout << fWidth << std::endl;
    cout << fHeight << std::endl;

    /*
    640 320
    480 240
    */

    const char* window_name = "output";
    namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_NORMAL);

    Mat frame;
    Size boardSize;
    boardSize.width = 9;
    boardSize.height = 6;

    int remaining_frames = 30;

    Mat K;//  = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, vK);
    Mat D;
    Mat identity = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

    vector<vector<Point2f> > img_points;
    vector<vector<Point3f> > obj_points(1);

    int sq_sz = 25;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++) {
            obj_points[0].push_back(Point3f(float(j * sq_sz), float(i * sq_sz), 0));
        }
    }

    obj_points.resize(remaining_frames, obj_points[0]);

    bool found = false;

    clock_t prevTimestamp = 0;
    int delay = 500;

    while (1) {

        frame = nextFrame(camera);

        bool blinkOutput = false;

        if (remaining_frames > 0) {
            vector<Point2f> corners;
            int chessBoardFlags = CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE;


            found = findChessboardCorners(frame, boardSize, corners, chessBoardFlags);


            if (found) {
                drawChessboardCorners(frame, boardSize, corners, found);
                if (clock() - prevTimestamp > delay*1e-3*CLOCKS_PER_SEC) {

                    Mat viewGray;
                    cvtColor(frame, viewGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                    cornerSubPix(viewGray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 30, 0.1));

                    img_points.push_back(corners);
                    remaining_frames--;
                    cout << remaining_frames << " frames to calibration." << endl;
                    blinkOutput = true;
                    prevTimestamp = clock();
                }

                if (remaining_frames == 0) {
                    cout << "Computing distortion" << endl;

                    int flags = 0;
                    flags |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;
                    flags |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND;
                    flags |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW;


                    fisheye::calibrate(obj_points, img_points, frame.size(), K, D, noArray(), noArray(), flags);
                    cout << "Finished computing distortion" << endl;
                    cout << K << endl;
                    cout << D << endl;
                }
            }

            if (blinkOutput) { bitwise_not(frame, frame); }
            cv::imshow(window_name, frame);
            if (waitKey(50) == 27) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            Mat output;

            fisheye::undistortImage(frame, output, K, D, identity);

            cv::imshow(window_name, output);
            if (waitKey(50) == 27) {
                break;
            }
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's why it's called FISHEYE.

Comment: can you post the original distorted image and draw the detected chessboard?

Comment: @Micka Updated the imgur link with the chess board and detected points

Comment: Not knowing the OpenCV fisheye function, I would have to go by the visual effect and suggest that the problem is in the setup. In particular, a fisheye camera has an optical centre around which the image is bent. The correction setup needs to know where in the input image this point is found, and it looks to me you're using `(0,0)`. But the OpenCV documentation is pretty rubbish.

Comment: did you try the non-fisheye calibration version? Try to use more images to cover (nearly)  the whole image area with the pattern.

Comment: @Micka I did try running the non fisheye undistort function. It displays an output image but the distortion isn't corrected because the camera model is different.